# kafka-console-producer.sh Error: Could not find or load main class kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Just installed a Docker image of spotify/kafka. sudo docker ps:

```
82c411a52a38        spotify/kafka                    "supervisord -n"         26 minutes ago      Up 26 minutes       0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp
```

Also, downloaded kafka binaries separately, so I could use the kafka-console-producer.sh to test the install, as per:  `https://hub.docker.com/r/spotify/kafka/`

I have the following ENV vars set:

KAFKA=event-ora-dev:9092
ZOOKEEPER=event-ora-dev:2181

When I run the command `./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list $KAFKA --topic test`

I get this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer
```

Assuming, that kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer is a java class, being invoked by kafka-console-producer.sh shell script - where should I be looking for this java class?

Answer (score 1):

If you download Kafka from the project website and extract it, there is sub folder `lib` containing all `jar` files.

`kafka-console-producer.sh` will need `kafka-tools-0.9.0.1.jar` for `kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer` (or different version -- not sure what you are using).

If you run `bin/kafka-console-producer.sh` from top level folder, this should work out-of-the box.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue using kafka 10: 
So as @Matthias J. Sax said I was missing some jars, 
So i found that when downloaded kafka_2.10-0.10.2.1 I was missing jars in lib 
and when I downloaded kafka_2.12-0.10.2.1 I got the full lib folder.

Bottom line I did as follows:

wget http://www-us.apache.org/dist/kafka/0.10.2.1/kafka_2.12-0.10.2.1.tgz

tar -xvf kafka_2.12-0.10.2.1.tgz

./kafka_2.12-0.10.2.1/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list $KAFKA --topic test